# How to to implement background functionalities in react native android application?

Tags: react-native

**I need do some functionalities in Android application background , so how to implement in my application ?**

Answer (score 0):

For **React Native Android** there is a native api called [Headless JS](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/headless-js-android.html#headless-js) for running js tasks while app is in background. You could also try
**[react-native-background-job](https://github.com/vikeri/react-native-background-job)** which is actually based on Headless JS.